# Can two set theories extending Z be different and yet bi-interpretable?

Tags: set-theory

At [Hamkins - Different set theories are never bi-interpretable](http://jdh.hamkins.org/different-set-theories-are-never-bi-interpretable/), it is mentioned that different set theories extending ZF are never bi-interpretable.

Where different means "not theoretically equivalent", i.e. there must be a theorem that one has and the other doesn't.

> Question: Would that same result hold for Z, i.e. is it the case that any different [in the same sense mentioned in that article] theories extending Z are never bi-interpretable?
>
> More generally: even if the above fails, the question is about whether this result needs the full strength of ZF, and if not then what would be the least fragment of ZF for which this result holds?

Comment: Certainly the *proof* seems to break down if we replace ZF with Z (for example, it requires the use of the Mostowski collapsing lemma, which requires replacement).

Comment: This question is one of the questions that Alfredo and I have been investigating, following up on the work to which you linked, and we have certain ideas, but we are not yet ready to announce our results.

Comment: in your article you said that different extensions of PA are never bi-interpretable, I think you mean "proper extensions of PA", do these extensions need to be  formulated in the language of PA, or you may accept Z which has a consistency strength stronger than PA, to be an "extension of PA"? if the latter is what you meant then clearly the question is solved, it is PA that is the cut-off! if there is such a thing I mean, since weaker theories than PA would clearly have PA and ZF-infinity that you've mentioned being bi-interpretable different theories.

Comment: A theory T extends a theory S, if every axiom of S is a theorem of T (and usually also one insists that the language of S is the same as the language of T). Zermelo's theory Z is not an extension of PA, because they are not expressed in the same language, and the axioms of PA are not amongst the theorems of Z.

Comment: @Joel  "the axioms of PA are not amongst the theorems of Z" wow, I wouldn't have expected that! I would have thought there was a model of PA in Z, namely ω, but it must be more subtle than that.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Yes, Z proves that $\omega$ is a model of PA, and from this it follows that PA is interpreted in Z. But the language of PA is the language of an ordered ring (with $+$, $\cdot$, $0$, $1$ and $<$) and the language of Z is the language of set theory (with $\in$), so in this (trivial) sense, the axioms of PA are not amongst the theorems of Z. But this prevents Z from being an "extension" of PA. Meanwhile, Z is an extension of the interpeted version of PA via the map $\psi\mapsto \psi^\omega$, relativizing arithmetic assertions $\psi$ to their interpretation in $\omega$.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I just thought that one can define 'extending' theories in a semantic manner as: a theory T extends a theory S iff every model of T is a model of S, also equivalence can be defined semantically as a theory T is equivalent to a theory S iff every model of T is a model of S and every model of S is a model of T. This way we don't require the languages of T and S to be the same for those purposes. So your argument for non bi-interpretability of extensions of ZF can be formulated in these terms, No?

Comment: The semantic notion is identical to my notion, since two theories $S$ and $T$ have the same models in language $\mathcal{L}$ if and only if they prove exactly the same theorems in that language. This follows from the completeness theorem for first-order logic. The point of the non-bi-interpretation result, and the enormous surprise of Enayat's theorem, is that one might have expected that ZF and ZFC or ZFC and ZFC+CH or ZFC+$\neg$CH might all have been bi-interpretable (and these theories are all in the language of set theory) but in fact none of them are.

Comment: they are not identical. I can have two theories that are semantically equivalent but yet not syntactically equivalent. Let theory T be just theory S but with its primitive symbols renamed in another signature,  i.e. axioms of T are just renaming of axioms of S, then those two theories are "distinct" syntactically speaking, but they are 'not distinct' semantically speaking, since they do have the same models. And I know very well the point you  (and Ali Enayat before you) are rising, and I'm not asking about that in my latest comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE (January 30, 2022):** The *first* question was answered (in the negative) by Hamkins and Freire for $\mathrm{Z}$ (Zermelo set theory) and $\mathrm{ZF}^{-}$ ($\mathrm{ZF}$ without powerset). Their paper "Bi-interpretation in weak set theories" was recently published in the Journal of Symbolic Logic. See [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.05262) for a preprint of their paper, and [here](http://jdh.hamkins.org/bi-interpretation-in-set-theory-oberwolfach-2022/) for recent blog of Hamkins about this topic. The *second* question remains open.

> What follows is my old answer (June 19, 2018).

To my knowledge the two questions you are asking are wide open; indeed the second question is one of the two open questions posed at the end of [this 2016 paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.07093) of mine, which gives many examples (and non-examples) of theories $T$ that satisfy the principle "different consistent extensions of $T$ are not bi-interpretable".

The aforementioned paper was published as:

A. Enayat, “Variations on a Visserian theme,” in Liber Amicorum Alberti: a tribute to Albert Visser, Jan van Eijck, Rosalie Iemhoff and Joost J. Joosten (eds.) Pages, 99-110. ISBN, 978-1848902046. College Publications, London, 2016.